# How to install nwchem by adding a launchpad source (not PPA)

Tags: software-installation, launchpad

I want to install NWChem (a molecular simulation package) and the link given for Ubuntu in their website is: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nwchem.

Can you please let me know how to add it to the sources file, so that I can use apt to install it?

I tried for the ppa but I could not find any at all.

Comment: There is no need to install it from source.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just simply run:

```
sudo apt install nwchem
```

it's a supported package which already exist in official repository, and the link you provide is the source of it.

The fact is that you already have access to the source of this package, if you want to download the source you can run:

```
apt source --download-only nwchem
```

And if you want to compile and install it from source code:

1. first install the built dependencies.

   ```
   sudo apt build-dep nwchem
   ```
2. then use this command to fetch and compile nwchem

   ```
   apt source --compile nwchem
   ```
3. then install it:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i nwchem-version.deb
   ```

or you can use things like gdebi to handle dependencies too.

Comment: You need 8 spaces to do code formatting when using numbering...  **:-)**

Comment: I was wondering why it's don't get the correct format, thanks ;)

Comment: Good you left a comment: I forgot to upvote a good answer!